# Silent printing using chrome app

Tags: printing, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to develop a chrome silent printing app but software programming solution not kiosk.please help me with this problem

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector("#convert").addEventListener("click",printContent);
};
          function printContent(){
  var restore=document.body.innerHTML;
  var print=document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML=print;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML=restore;
}
```

How to do changes?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do and what you are asking?  This question is too broad currently.

Comment: I am developing a chrome app .. for printing specifically silent printing.. i got how to print using chrome app.. but i want a solution for silent printing that is no dialogue box should appear before printing

Comment: Ahh... you won't be able to disable that from a chrome extension.  The only way to do that is with some hacky changes a user would have to make.

Comment: that means kiosk mode in chrome.. ? there was NPAPI but not its deprecated .. i want some solution help me

Comment: Wanting for a solution does not make it appear. AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: Actually, apparently you can with `--kiosk --kiosk-printing` switches.

Comment: i want a solution that didn't use --kiosk

Comment: Then, no, with 90% confidence.